# Making Mage calls from Magento Test Automation Framework

Tags: magento

We're writing test automation scripts using Magento Test Automation Framework. We'd like to make Mage:: calls inside the scripts. For example, `Mage::getModel('customer/customer')` and `Mage::getModel('customer/session')`.

How can this be done?

Up to now this error is being thrown:

```
Call to a member function getModelInstance() on a non-object in C:\Development\Magento\Enterprise\mothercare\app\Mage.php on line 432
```

Thanks in advance,